# Integrate Intervention library with Laravel (serve scaled images)

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

Im getting this issue "Serve scaled images" issue like:

> https://....ngrok.io/uploads/posts/img1.png is     resized in HTML
>   or CSS from 800x400 to 251x119.    Serving a scaled image could save
>   173.3KiB (90% reduction).

So maybe using the Intervention library can help to solve the issue. But Im not understanding how to properly use the library with Laravel.

I installed with "`composer install intervention/image`". But then in the documentation example for Laravel:

```
// usage inside a laravel route
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $img = Image::make('foo.jpg')->resize(300, 200);

    return $img->response('jpg');
});
```

But Im not understanding how to apply this example to the image shown in the show.blade.php file?

For now the image is presented in the show.blade.php like:

```
 <img class="card-img-top img-fluid"
 style="max-height: 121px; border:1px solid #eee;"
 src="{{ 
 $post->image == null 
 ? url('img/default.png') :    url($post->image)}}"  alt="Card image cap">
```

Comment: Are you trying to upload an image, store it, then display it?

Comment: No, the image is already stored,  in the show.blade.php is just display.